# Unauthorized access with spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I try to add security to a rest application.

I followed this tutorial: http://www.codesandnotes.be/2014/10/31/restful-authentication-using-spring-security-on-spring-boot-and-jquery-as-a-web-client/

I configured my class who extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.

```java
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/rest/**").authenticated();
http.csrf().disable();
http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);
http.formLogin().successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler);
http.formLogin().failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler);
```

I have an login.html, index.html who load (via jquery) some other html file in index.html.

I try to access a service with curl

```
curl -i -X POST -d username=test -d password=test http://localhost:8080/rest/cities
```

I get a

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
```

All url with rest is secured, but i provide username and password should word.

When i debug, i see then my class who implements UserDetailsService who have the method loadUserByUsername is never called.

There is something who don't do the link correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be logged in to access restricted resources. Spring security provides a default entry point for performing your authentication. That's what this part of your given link does:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#loginform').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var data = 'username=' + $('#username').val() + '&password=' + $('#password').val();
        $.ajax({
            data: data,
            timeout: 1000,
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/login'

        }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            var preLoginInfo = JSON.parse($.cookie('dashboard.pre.login.request'));
            window.location = preLoginInfo.url;

        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('Booh! Wrong credentials, try again!');
        });
    });
});
```

So you need to *POST* the */login* url with your *username* and *password* parameters. That's how it's done with curl:

```
curl -i -X POST -d username=user -d password=userPass -c /opt/cookies.txt 
http://localhost:8080/rest/login
```

What this does is to log in with your credentials and store the given cookie in the *cookies.txt* file. Then, you'll need just to attach that cookie in every single request performed to gain permission in your server:

```
curl -i --header "Accept:application/json" -X GET -b /opt/cookies.txt 
http://localhost:8080/rest/cities
```

**See also:**

- [Spring Security for a REST API](http://www.baeldung.com/2011/10/31/securing-a-restful-web-service-with-spring-security-3-1-part-3/)

Comment: thank that work, just need to see if there a a way to protect my html file.